TinyMCE image_upload_handler hangs with Cloud Storage
I am trying to get tinyMce to upload an image to Cloud Storage when composing an email from within my app.
I am developing with Angular 18, @angular/fire 18 modular (Firestore, Storage, Functions, Auth).
Everything seems to work ok. The image is uploaded, and I get an image url, but the image dialog doesn't dismiss, and I am not seeing any errors in the console.
this is my code:
images_upload_handler: (blobInfo) => {
        const file = blobInfo.blob();
        const filePath = `${Date.now()}-${blobInfo.filename()}`;
        
        // Initialize Firebase Storage and create a reference to the file path
        const storage = getStorage();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, filePath);
        
        // Start the file upload
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
      
        // Return a Promise that resolves with the download URL once the upload completes
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
          uploadTask.on(
            'state_changed',
            (snapshot) => {
              // Optional: log or handle the upload progress if needed
              const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
              console.log(`Upload progress: ${progress}%`);
            },
            (error) => {
              // Handle unsuccessful uploads
              console.error('Upload failed:', error);
              reject('Image upload failed');
            },
            async () => {
              // Get the download URL after the upload completes
              try {
                const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
                resolve(downloadURL);
              } catch (error) {
                console.error('Failed to retrieve download URL:', error);
                reject('Failed to retrieve download URL');
              }
            }
          );
        });
      },

I have even just used the code from tinymce's github example, and i get the same result:
https://github.com/EbukaPeter55/Angular-TinyMCE/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts
    images_upload_handler: (blobInfo) => {
      const file = blobInfo.blob();
      const filePath = `${Date.now()}-${blobInfo.filename()}`;
      const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
      const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

      const promise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        task
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            finalize(() =>
              ref
                .getDownloadURL()
                .pipe(last())
                .subscribe((url) => {
                  resolve(url);
                })
            )
          )
          .subscribe((_) => {
            // do nothing
          });
      });
      return promise;
    },
  };

I can't see why this is happening or how to call dismiss dialog when the image is uploaded and I receive the downloadUrl.
can anyone shed some light as to what may be the issue please?

The issue appears to be with tinymce and/or your code but not google-cloud-storage. Please consider dropping the google-cloud-storage tag.
